# CORS issues in Angular 8 REST API

Tags: angular, cors

I have 2 components :

My first component "CurrenciesComponent" is loading

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-currencies',
  templateUrl: './currencies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./currencies.component.css'],
  providers: [ CryptoCurrencyService ]
})
export class CurrenciesComponent implements OnInit {
  currency: CryptoCurrency;
  currencies: Array <CryptoCurrency> = [];

  // dependency injection
  constructor(private cryptoCurrencyService: CryptoCurrencyService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cryptoCurrencyService.getAll().subscribe(res => {
      this.currencies = res;
    });
  }
}
```

On the html file i'm passing the currencies array :

```
<app-currency
    *ngFor="let currency of currencies"
    [currency] = "currency"

>
```

In the child component i retrive an @Input() currency: CryptoCurrency.
Now my issue is that this object passed to the child component is used to make a call to a service.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-currency',
  templateUrl: './currency.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./currency.component.css']
})
export class CurrencyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() currency: CryptoCurrency;
  basicCurrencyExchange: BasicCurrencyExchange;

  constructor(private cryptoCurrencyService: CryptoCurrencyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cryptoCurrencyService.getCrypto(this.currency).subscribe(res => {
      this.basicCurrencyExchange = res;

    })
  }
}
```

I created a model (BasicCurrencyExchange) with 3 params : eur, uds, yen

```
export class BasicCurrencyExchange {
  constructor(private _usd: string, private _jpy: string, private _eur: string) {
  }
  ... getters + setters
}
```

In the service I call this method:

```
getCrypto(currency: CryptoCurrency) {
  var header = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Apikey': 'myApiKeyValue',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      })
  };
  return this.http.get<BasicCurrencyExchange>(this.baseUrlCrypto + "/price?fsym=" + currency.symbol + "&tsyms=USD,JPY,EUR", header);
}
```

For a reason that i don't figure out, i don't return the values expected in the HTLM file.

I have 2 errors :

1. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=btc&tsyms=USD,JPY,EUR' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
2. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'eur' of undefined whereas this property exist in the returned object

THe expected object that is returned should be the following

USD: 8655.82
JPY: 953412.95
EUR: 7822.62

Comment: CORS issues mean your **server** is not correctly configured. The issue is not in your angular app but in your server app.

Comment: the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` header needs to be set on the server configuration.

Comment: In fact, it seems the server is fine, but you're making it fail by sending the useless, and rejected (as the error explains) Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Don't add this header to your request. Regarding the second error: it's caused by code you haven't posted, since nowhere in the posted code you're trying to access the property eur of anything.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by JB Nizet, Mic and Nicolas : 
1 /Access control was useless 
2/ I didn't noticed that it was "case sensitive". In the HTML i was calling {{ basicCurrencyExchange.usd }} instead of {{ basicCurrencyExchange.USD }}

It solved one part of my issue : i can display the values as I expect. 
I replaced the previous code with this one :

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.cryptoCurrencyService.getCrypto(this.currency)
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.basicCurrencyExchange = res;
      console.log(this.basicCurrencyExchange);
      resolve(this.basicCurrencyExchange);
  });
})
```

Now i can display the values but i still have the undefined error message...